# Volumetric shader transparency direction

Tags: shaders, shader-nodes

I am creating an object that I want to be transparent in a specific direction considering the object normals, but Blender gives me transparency considering only global parameters. I think it explains better with the sketch below.

[image]

This is how my Shader Editor currently looks

[image]

I've been thinking about using UVs or even weight maps to tell Blender where I want the transparency to start from, but can't get around how to do that

Can I get some help?